# Rounded borders on td elements

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-9, rounded-corners

I've got a table and inside of it I'm trying to give each td element rounded corners through css3. This works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari but not Opera and IE9. I just have to make this work for IE9 maybe someone knows what I'm doing wrong. I'm going to give pieces of the code cause there is a lot.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
</head>

<div class="timeline_page_wrapper">

<div class="wrap">
<table class="events_table">

<tr>
<th id="oct12">October</th>
<th id="nov12">November</th>
<th id="dec12">December</th>
<th id="jan13">January</th>
</tr>

<td class="event fn_milestone fn_healthcare fn_regulation fn_priority_med  priority2 ">
<a class="inline-cBox" href="#milestone_3">
<div class="content">Again, Not Very Important</div>
    <div class="lower">
<hr>
<span class="date">10.2012</span>
<span class="type">Regulation</span>
    <img src="http://policyapp.beamland.com/img/icon-medical.png" alt="" height="21px" />
</div>
</a>
</td>
```

And the CSS:

```
td.event {
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -ms-border-radius:12px;
    -o-border-radius:12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:
    0 1px 2px #fff, /*bottom external highlight*/
    1px 1px 1px #666, /*side right external shadow*/
    inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), /*bottom internal shadow*/
    inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8), /*top internal highlight*/
    inset -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*side right internal highlight*/
    box-shadow:
       0 1px 2px #fff, /*bottom external highlight*/
       1px 1px 1px #666, /*side right external shadow*/
       inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), /*bottom internal shadow*/
       inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8), /*top internal highlight*/
       inset -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*side right internal highlight*/
    behavior: url('../pie/PIE.htc');
   }
```

When I look at the web inspector for IE9 it shows the borders being applied but dosen't show up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's work in my ie9. CHECK this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PwBva/)

Comment: check this [image](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=b10efaf)

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question because I didn't give enough of the CSS when I asked the question. Apparently IE 9 does not like you to use gradients and rounded corners at the same time. That was the problem I was having but didn't realize it. So I solved this by just using a solid color and voila the rounded borders appear.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
border-radius: 12px;
border-top-left-radius: 12px;
border-top-right-radius: 12px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
```

E9 will use the default `border-radius`, so just make sure you include that in all your styles calling a border radius. Then your site will be ready for IE9.

`-moz-border-radius` is for Firefox, `-webkit-border-radius` is for Safari and Chrome.

Furthermore: don't forget to declare your IE coding is ie9:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

It is not planned for IE8. See the [CSS Compatibility page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I wish it were that easy but I've already tried that. If you look at the head of the code I put up I have: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1"> So I tried changing it to content="IE=9" but to no avail. I even tried putting in the specific border-top-left-radius as opposed to just border-radius, but nothing seems to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I cleared browser history and cache etc. So basically what you are telling me is that for IE9 border-radius should work on a td element. Is that correct?